# Python: create dict from list and auto-gen/increment the keys (list is the actual key values)?

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

i've searched pretty hard and cant find a question that exactly pertains to what i want to..

I have a file called "words" that has about 1000 lines of random A-Z sorted words...

```
10th
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
a
AAA
AAAS
Aarhus
Aaron
AAU
ABA
Ababa
aback
abacus
abalone
abandon
abase
abash
abate
abater
abbas
abbe
abbey
abbot
Abbott
abbreviate
abc
abdicate
abdomen
abdominal
abduct
Abe
abed
Abel
Abelian
```

I am trying to load this file into a dictionary, where using the word are the key values and the keys are actually auto-gen/auto-incremented for each word

e.g {0:10th, 1:1st, 2:2nd} ...etc..etc...

below is the code i've hobbled together so far, it seems to *sort of* works but its only showing me the last entry in the file as the only dict pair element

```
f3data = open('words')

mydict = {}

for line in f3data:
    print line.strip()
    cmyline = line.split()
    key = +1
    mydict [key] = cmyline

print mydict
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
key = +1
```

`+1` is the same thing as `1`. I assume you meant `key += 1`. I also can't see a reason why you'd `split` each line when there's only one item per line.

However, there's really no reason to do the looping yourself.

```
with open('words') as f3data:
    mydict = dict(enumerate(line.strip() for line in f3data))
```

Comment: i was using split() to remove the "\n" char at the end of each word.  I tried .strip() but it threw and error.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than that. `.strip()` is tried, tested and true.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I was working this on my own and while others have a much more python way of doing it, I was trying to make the original code work. I think the key increment was the only line I didn't consider...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it was because I was doing the split then strip -- which is what was throwing the error.  Yes, your absolutely correct, its tried/true/tested and of course now works without error for me

Comment: Of course; splitting creates a list, which can't be stripped because lists aren't strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(enumerate(x.rstrip() for x in f3data))
```

But your error is `key += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The use of zero-based numeric keys in a `dict` is very suspicious. Consider whether a simple [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) would suffice.

Here is an example using a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> mylist = [word.strip() for word in open('/usr/share/dict/words')]
>>> mylist[1]
'A'
>>> mylist[10]
"Aaron's"
>>> mylist[100]
"Addie's"
>>> mylist[1000]
"Armand's"
>>> mylist[10000]
"Loyd's"
```

I use [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove whitespace and newlines, which are present in `/usr/share/dict/words`. This may not be necessary with your data.

However, if you *really* need a dictionary, Python's [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function is your friend here, and you can pass the output directly into the [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) function to create it:

```
>>> mydict = dict(enumerate(word.strip() for word in open('/usr/share/dict/words')))
>>> mydict[1]
'A'
>>> mydict[10]
"Aaron's"
>>> mydict[100]
"Addie's"
>>> mydict[1000]
"Armand's"
>>> mydict[10000]
"Loyd's"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f3data = open('words')
print f3data.readlines()
```

Comment: yeah, and the keys are indexes - that's called list in the land of the sense programmers.

Answer (score 0):

With keys that dense, you don't want a dict, you want a list.

```
with open('words') as fp:
    data = map(str.strip, fp.readlines())
```

But if you really can't live without a dict:

```
with open('words') as fp:
    data = dict(enumerate(X.strip() for X in fp))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{index: x.strip() for index, x in enumerate(open('filename.txt'))}
```

This code uses a dictionary comprehension and the `enumerate` built-in, which takes an input sequence (in this case, the file object, which yields each line when iterated through) and returns an index along with the item. Then, a dictionary is built up with the index and text.

One question: why not just use a list if all of your keys are integers?

Finally, your original code should be

```
f3data = open('words')

mydict = {}

for index, line in enumerate(f3data):
    cmyline = line.strip()
    mydict[index] = cmyline

print mydict
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Dictionary comprehensions work in Python 2.7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the words in a dict makes no sense. If you're using numbers as keys you should be using a list.

```
from __future__ import with_statement

with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


words = {}

for n, line in enumerate(lines):
    words[n] = line.strip()

print words
```