# Converting list to dictionary with list elements as index - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From [Python: create dict from list and auto-gen/increment the keys (list is the actual key values)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974959/python-create-dict-from-list-and-auto-gen-increment-the-keys-list-is-the-actua), it's possible to create a `dict` from a `list` using `enumerate` to generate tuples made up of incremental keys and elements in life, i.e.:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(enumerate(x))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
>>> dict(enumerate(x))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

It is also possible to reverse the key-value by iterating through every key in the `dict` (assuming that there is a one-to-one mapping between key-value pairs:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> d = dict(enumerate(x))
>>> {v:k for k,v in d.items()}
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Given the input list `['a', 'b', 'c']`, how can achieve the dictionary where the elements as the key and incremental index as values **without trying to loop an additional time to reverse the dictionary**?

Comment: `enumerate(i for i in x)` is the same as `enumerate(x)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm sooo blind at the last hour of work on a friday. hahahaa...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Convert list to dictionary with indexes as values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459969/python-convert-list-to-dictionary-with-indexes-as-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> {j:i for i,j in enumerate(x)}
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: Dictionary comprehension!?